# Animate shape along a stroke in an SVG

Tags: svg

```html
<svg width="160" height="160" viewBox="0 0 160 160"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <path d="M 40 120 l 80 0 l -40 -69.28203 z" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="6" />
</svg>
```

I have this equilateral triangle and I would like to, inside of the stroke, have an arrowhead that looks like a double-wedge and animates along the stroke, infinitely.
Like an arrow made of light, with a gradient trailing it. Possibly 3 of those at equal distance.

I've been looking into animation and the one thing I could come up with is the dasharray method. I thought that it might be possible to simply draw another triangle above this one in a different color. But I don't think it's possible, because there's no `stroke-linecap` with a pointy double-wedge and also I don't think the effect with the trailing gradient can be done with this method.

Then I thought it might be possible to animate a marker along the path, but I realized that it would lead to awkward behavior at the edges.

I'm at a total loss on how to do this and I would be very gateful for some guidance or ideas.

I've drawn a mockup to better illustrate what it's supposed to look like:
[image]

Comment: Not easy. Perhaps you could create the illusion of the corner turn by hiding (masking) the arrowhead, and having a new arrow coming out from the masking area.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this with a marker by animating refX, refY and orient. Here is a version just showing an refX animation. You'd probably need to write a long values array with a value per animation tick for each of refX, refY and orient to do exactly what you want, but its possible.

I'd probably suggest just writing a separate shape and animating it with pure javascript because markers are very tricky if you want cross-browser compatibility.

```html
<svg width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="30 30 100 100"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient2">
            <stop offset="0%"  stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="blue"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <marker id="Triangle" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="5" refY="5"
        markerWidth="1" markerHeight="6" orient="0">
      <path d="M 6 0 L 10 5 L 6 10 z" fill="blue"/>
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="6" height="10" fill="url(#gradient2)"/>
      <animate attributeName="refX" values="0;-125" dur="5s"/>
    </marker>

  </defs>
  
    <path d="M 40 120 l 80 0 l -40 -69.28203 z" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="6" marker-start="url(#Triangle)" />
  
</svg>
```